# Which files/directories should I move to ramdisk to improve Chrome performance?

Tags: google-chrome, tmpfs

I am running Ubuntu 19 and Chrome 79 on a laptop with a slow and noisy hard drive. I have 12 GB of RAM which is rarely full.

I find that opening a web page in Chrome is very slow and creates a lot of disk activity, verified with `iotop`. What I want to do is to map directories that Chrome uses to `ramdisk` to reduce the trashing and improve browsing performance.

I've already moved `~/.cache/google-chrome` and things have improved. However I can still hear a lot of Chrome disk activity as I open each new page.

What else can I safely move to `ramdisk`? I'm happy to take the risk of moving everything there and having an rsync/cron task to harden key files every minute or so.

Comment: With the current price of SSD and christmas coming , you have 2 solutions , you get someone to buy you a SSD DRIVE or you buy it yourself. Your laptop is going to be so good you'll be scratching your head: "Why did I wait so long ?" , keep your current hdd as an external backup.

Comment: I hear you. However,  even with SSD I would look to reduce the amount of disk activity in order to prolong its life.